# Is ajax site content protection possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, web

I was thinking about creating a site that just loads the site content from a .txt file or something like that through and AJAX connection with jquery. The thing is, If I do that,can't people (by people I mean hackers and what not) just come along and change around my .txt file, and is there a way I can secure this?

Comment: How would someone change a text file stored on the server?

Comment: Thats kinda what my question is trying to get out.

Comment: If you've got a server set up such that random people can change files on it, then it kind-of doesn't matter what your site architecture is.

Comment: @user1938700 If someone (like hackers) could edit a file stored on a server then I think every website would be dead. JavaScript, CSS, PHP, HTML, and all other types of files would be able to be edited. That would be pretty bad. But no, a file can't be edited unless the person has access to the server.

Comment: So then, is there a way to make the text file unreadable to a user if a user types in the url for it in the browser, but the site to access it to render?

Comment: I think it would be pretty hard to make a site out of a basic text file (why not HTML?)... but yes there might be a way to make it unreadable in normal HTTP requests but you're going to need to use PHP or another server-side language for this (I'll post an answer about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the AJAX request has the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` with it (jQuery ajax requests have this) then you can redirect the user away from the file with PHP like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest') { 
   // if not ajax request, then redirect to homepage
   header("Location: /"); 
   exit; 
}
?>
```

If this is at the top of the text file, then it will work but you will have to request the text file with the `.php` extension rather than `.txt` but it will still be a text file because the first `header()` call sets it to plain text.

Comment: Just if you want a naive approach

Comment: very simple to add a header to a request... nothing fail safe about `X-Requested-With`...it's only a convenience

Comment: @charlietfl This is the only way I know of. If you know of a better way feel free to post an answer about it.

Comment: @Nathan am only pointing out that it is not a security mechanism that isn't very easily thwarted

Comment: @Nathan  I  used to think so too... but now I realize it is only a convenience method since headers can be easily maniplulated

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah but it's still better than having nothing at all.

Comment: In what world this is a protection from anything? "Yeah but it's still better than having nothing at all" --- in what way? Pretending you're protected is even worse than not having protection at all.

Comment: The question is specifically about 'hackers and what not', I think they'll all be capable of installing a [Firefox Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/modify-headers/)

Answer (score 4):

> The thing is, If I do that,can't people (by people I mean hackers and what not) just come along and change around my .txt file

Not unless they have access to your server, no.

They can, of course, read the .txt file from your server and do with that content whatever they want. But they can't make *your* site do something else with it without hacking your site. (And in that respect, it doesn't matter whether it's a .txt file or just a normal HTML file.)

Comment: *Nobody ever expects the **Spanish Inquisition**!*

Comment: So then, is there a way to make the text file unreadable to a user if a user types in the url for it in the browser, but the site to access it to render?

Comment: @user1938700: You can do things to make it difficult (server-side checks that deny access to the .txt file if that same client hasn't recently grabbed your .html file or whatever, do one-time-access tokens so the request has the token with it, and check the token server-side to make sure it's being requested by the same IP address and hasn't been requested before, etc., etc.), but if it's just web content, why bother? Again, this is no different from normal web content, which is completely accessible.

Comment: @user1938700 - You could start with some early 20th century English countryside poetry, and then maybe move on to the beatnecks, but the lesser ones, the onew without any talent. End on *American Psycho* and you'd well-nigh have an unuexusable, *unexplaibable*, and unreadable travesty of the human condition.

Answer (score 1):

Without having access to your server, bad people are not able to change the .txt-file (btw it doesn't matter which file-type you use). So keep your password etc. secure and your are on the safe side.